# Is it permissible to have relationships to parents of parents for JSON:API resources?

Tags: design-patterns, api, api-design, json

I have the following hierarchy:

```
venue -> concert -> booking
```

And within booking I have a relationship for the concert. But should the booking also have a relationship to the venue? Or is it bad practice to have relationships at that depth?

What about if there was also a seat in a booking? Would a relationship to venue still be reasonable?

Or is it better to instead do two requests to get the venue? E.g. use the booking -> concert relationship to then get the relationship between the concert and venue?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea. But not because of anything to do with json.

The problem with putting the venue reference in two places is that you can end up with two different values.

Comment: Could you expand on that? How would I end up with two different values?

Comment: @LeviH: Booking A refers to concert A and to venue A. However, the entity of concert A itself refers to venue B. In which venue is concert A taking place? In which venue is booking A taking place? Because there are two sources of truth on venue reference (i.e. from bookings and concerts), you open the door to these two sources contradicting one another.